# Trouble with N1QL query and index in Couchbase

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I have a straightforward N1QL query:

```
"select xrefId, CLSTR, CLUSTER_NAME, SHORTENED_NAME, "
        + "PRMRY, SET_NUM, TYPE from myBucket "
        + "where _class=\"com.package.model.ClusterCodeXref\"
```

And a corresponding secondary index (I'm not allowed to create a primary index on this bucket for internal reasons):

```
CREATE INDEX `idx_xref` ON `myBucket`(`xrefId`,`CLSTR`,`CLUSTER_NAME`,
`SHORTENED_NAME`,`PRMRY`,`SET_NUM`,`TYPE`)
where _class=`com.package.model.ClusterCodeXref` using GSI
```

Yet when I run the query (using spring-data-couchbase), I get the following error:

```
"No index available on keyspace myBucket that matches your query. 
Use CREATE INDEX or CREATE PRIMARY INDEX to create an index, or check that your expected index is online."
```

Can someone explain what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The leading index key and Index WHERE clause needs to be present in Query WHERE clause to choose the index.
The index where clause using back-ticks ( it means field in the document). Change those to double quotes and add _class as leading index key like below.

```
CREATE INDEX `idx_xref` ON `myBucket`(_class, `xrefId`,`CLSTR`,`CLUSTER_NAME`,
`SHORTENED_NAME`,`PRMRY`,`SET_NUM`,`TYPE`)
where _class="com.package.model.ClusterCodeXref" using GSI
```

Comment: You are so right! It was the back ticks that I had wrong, as well as the leading field. I spent an hour on the phone with our Couchbase rep before we figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
SELECT custom_data.xrefId, custom_data.CLSTR, custom_data.CLUSTER_NAME, custom_data.SHORTENED_NAME, custom_data.PRMRY, custom_data.SET_NUM, custom_data.TYPE
FROM `myBucket` AS custom_data
WHERE  (`_class` = "com.package.model.ClusterCodeXref");
```

In String format:

```
"SELECT custom_data.xrefId, custom_data.CLSTR, "
      + "custom_data.CLUSTER_NAME, custom_data.SHORTENED_NAME, " 
      + "custom_data.PRMRY, custom_data.SET_NUM, " 
      + "custom_data.TYPE "
      + "FROM `myBucket` AS custom_data "
      + "WHERE  (`_class` = \"com.package.model.ClusterCodeXref\");"
```

Comment: Thanks. But aliasing the table had no effect. I get the same error.

Comment: The console shows it as 100% built. Is there another step I should have taken?